# Rendering issue in views in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rendering

The code in the view shall give the books in the database

```
<% @bookmark.each do |book| %>
```

works only for multiple rows. If i had single row, it would show error like

```
" undefined method `each' for #<Bookmark:0x3e2e3f0> "
```

What should i do to print single row also. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<% @array_bookmark = @bookmark.class == Array ? @bookmark : [@bookmark] %>
<% @array_bookmark.each do |book| %>
```

Comment: @abhi-ram-a If it solved your problem, then you should mark it as accepted. Click the tick mark next to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap `@bookmark` in `Array()`, like this:

```
<% Array(@bookmark).each do |book| %>
```

Incidentally you should really rename `@bookmark` to `@bookmarks`.