# Rendering issue in view of ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rendering

I am rendering a variable from the controller action . The code is :

```
def show1
  if request.post?
    @bookmark = Bookmark.all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @bookmark }
    end
  end  
end
```

This is the action 'show'. The 'show' view is as follows:

```
<% @array_bookmark = @bookmark.class == Array ? @bookmark : [@bookmark] %>
<% @array_bookmark.each do |book| %>
<li><%= book.url%>
<b>Title:</b>
<li><%= book.title%>
<% end %>
```

This should print the records in bookmarks table with attributes url and title. But it gives an error:

```
NoMethodError in Bookmark#show

Showing C:/Sites/newapp/app/views/bookmark/show.html.erb where line #10 raised:

undefined method `url' for nil:NilClass

Extracted source (around line #10):

7:   <b>Url:</b>
8: <% @array_bookmark = @bookmark.class == Array ? @bookmark : [@bookmark] %>
9: <% @array_bookmark.each do |book| %>
10:   <li><%= book.url%></li>
11:   <b>Title:</b>
12:   <li><%= book.title%></li>
13:   <li><%= book.tags%></li>
```

This is the error i get . Can i anyone gimme a proper solution so that i can print the table records in the view properly?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you should have used [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13836591/rendering-issue-in-views-in-ruby-on-rails/13837018#13837018) to your earlier question:

```
<% Array(@bookmark).each do |book| %>
```

The code you have checks whether `@bookmark` is an instance of the class `Array`; if it is nil, this will return false and `@array_bookmark` will be assigned `[nil]`. Then when you iterate over it in your `each` loop you'll get a `nil` value for `book`. By using `Array()` you avoid this problem: `Array(nil)` evaluates to an empty array, so the loop never executes and you don't get an error.